# Get return type of child class in typescript

Tags: typescript

my struggle with Typescript is to get return type of class function which is child of parent class. All I can achieve is to get return type from parent class.

I added snippet with explanatory comments on what I need to achieve at the end.

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20StepResult%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20GetCompanyExecute%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BaseStep%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20async%20execute()%3A%20Promise%3CStepResult%3Cany%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20data%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20GetCompany%20extends%20BaseStep%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20async%20execute()%3A%20Promise%3CStepResult%3CGetCompanyExecute%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20data%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20T%20from%20Promise%3CT%3E%0D%0Atype%20ThenArg%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20Promise%3Cinfer%20U%3E%20%3F%20U%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cinfer%20L%3E%20%3F%20L%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20T%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20getData%20%3D%20async%20%3CT%20extends%20BaseStep%3E(StepClass%3A%20typeof%20BaseStep)%3A%20Promise%3CThenArg%3CT%5B'execute'%5D%3E%5B'data'%5D%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%201%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A(async%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20TODO%3A%20I%20need%20to%20get%20%22GetCompanyExecute%22%20here%20as%20returned%20type%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20but%20it%20returns%20any%20which%20is%20return%20type%20of%20BaseStep%0D%0A%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20await%20getData(GetCompany)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20is%20return%20type%20I%20want%20%60await%20getData(GetCompany)%60%20to%20be%3A%0D%0A%20%20type%20X%20%3D%20ThenArg%3CGetCompany%5B'execute'%5D%3E%5B'data'%5D%20%20%0D%0A%7D))

```
export interface StepResult<T> {
  data: T;
}

export interface GetCompanyExecute {
  a: number;
}

class BaseStep {
  public async execute(): Promise<StepResult<any>> {
    return { data: {} }
  }
}

class GetCompany extends BaseStep {
  public async execute(): Promise<StepResult<GetCompanyExecute>> {
    return { data: { a: 1 } }
  }
}

// T from Promise<T>
type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U :
  T extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<infer L> ? L :
  T

const getData = async <T extends BaseStep>(StepClass: typeof BaseStep): Promise<ThenArg<T['execute']>['data']> => {
  return 1 as any;
}

(async () => {
  // TODO: I need to get "GetCompanyExecute" here as returned type
  // but it returns any which is return type of BaseStep
  const a = await getData(GetCompany)

  // This is return type I want `await getData(GetCompany)` to be:
  type X = ThenArg<GetCompany['execute']>['data']  
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const getData = async <T extends BaseStep>(StepClass: new () => T): Promise<ThenArg<T['execute']>['data']> => {
  return 1;
}

(async () => {
  const a = await getData(GetCompany) // typeof a === GetCompanyExecute
})
```

hope this can help you

Comment: It worked, thank you a lot :) 
in my actual case constructor got extra arguments so I argument was:
`StepClass: new (...args: any[]) => T`